# SumByColor with another condition

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check another condition for a diff cell along with active cell color. I added below in the IF but this gives #name? error. Can someone please help?

```
Function SumByColor(CellColor As Range, rRange As Range)
Dim cSum As Long
Dim ColIndex As Integer
Dim ross As Long
ColIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each cl In rRange
  ross = ActiveCell.Row
  If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = ColIndex And Cells(ross, "C").Value = "" Then
    cSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cl, cSum)
  End If
Next cl
SumByColor = cSum
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I do not think you wanted to use `ActiveCell` in your formula? Did you? Now, if it is in the `C` column, a circular reference is created.
2. Maybe you get an error because `cl` is not defined. Use this line to define the variable somewhere in the beginning: `Dim cl As Range`.
3. You will always get #NAME? error if your formula is put in the wrong place. Make sure the formula is NOT put in any "Sheet" module or "ThisWorkbook" module. A separate module (default name: "Module1") should be created (Insert > Module) for storing user defined formulas in order to be able to be used.

For me it works well if I put your formula anywhere except C column.

Comment: Hi @ZygD, Thanks a lot. The problem was due to point3 in your Answer. It is not giving error any more.

Comment: I need another help please. I was able to make the code work. But when I change the cell color the function does not recalculate the sum... is it possible to automate it whenever the cellcolor changes. It now only works when I go to the cell with the formula and press 'F2'.

Comment: @Amitabha Happy it helped. Unfortunately VBA does not have such event to capture format changes. If your workbook is not full of calculations I might suggest forcing recalculation every time when selection is changed. This is not exactly what you want, but I have no other simple answer. Insert the following 3 lines into the "Sheet" module (this time - not the "Module1"). `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`
    `Application.CalculateFull`
`End Sub`